# Rate It Button: It's possible to know if the user has voted your app in google play?

Tags: android, google-play

Wellcome guys, i have one app published, and i want to add a button that redirects the users directly into the vote screen of googleplay for my app. I dont want to open googleplay for my app, i want to open vote screen. How is possible to achieve that?

I tested this way: http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater

It doesn't works like i want, that way only opens googleplay website of your app, but not vote screen directly, but at least it redirects the user to googleplay, and i can't find a better way to achieve it.

OK, now, i know how to redirect the user to google play but..... **How can i know if the user has been voted or not my app?**

And also, **exists a way to redirect the user directly to google play's vote formulary for my app?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't know if they did. You can just assume they did after you redirected them.
Also, there is no option to redirect to the voting page directly.